# fio: how to test for bs less than 1 filesystem-block size?

Tags: ssd, fio

I am testing my SSDs and have two questions.

1. SNIA has published specification [PTS (SNIA)](https://www.snia.org/sites/default/files/technical_work/PTS/SSS_PTS_2.0.1.pdf) to test SSD . In many cases, it requires device to be tested for bs=0.5Ki !! What is the rational behind this? If I understand it right, the intent here is to assess the performance for IOs of smaller than 1 block size. Please correct me if I am wrong here in my understanding.
2. How to test this scenerio using fio? Since, I think, fio expects bs to be aligned to filesystem-blocksize. For example, in my case it failed with following error.

   `[root@system pwd]# /bin/fio --name=iops-wdpc --direct=1 --ioengine=libaio --bs=512 --size=1024Gi --numjobs=1 --thread=1 --iodepth=1 --output=op --allow_mounted_write=1 --filename=/dev/nvme2n1 --rw=write`

   `fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Invalid argument: write offset=6295552, buflen=512`

(my filesystem-blocksize is 4Ki)

```
[root@system pwd]# tune2fs -l /dev/nvme2n1 | grep -i 'block size'
Block size:               4096
```

(fio does not work with bs=512, 1024, 2048 and works for bs=4096)

```
[root@system ~]#  /bin/fio --name=iops-wdpc --direct=1 --ioengine=libaio --bs=512 --size=1024Gi --numjobs=1 --thread=1 --iodepth=1 --output=op --allow_mounted_write=1 --filename=/dev/nvme2n1 --rw=write
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Invalid argument: write offset=6295552, buflen=512
[root@system ~]# 
[root@system ~]#  /bin/fio --name=iops-wdpc --direct=1 --ioengine=libaio --bs=1024 --size=1024Gi --numjobs=1 --thread=1 --iodepth=1 --output=op --allow_mounted_write=1 --filename=/dev/nvme2n1 --rw=write
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Invalid argument: write offset=6295552, buflen=1024
[root@system ~]#
[root@system ~]#  /bin/fio --name=iops-wdpc --direct=1 --ioengine=libaio --bs=2048 --size=1024Gi --numjobs=1 --thread=1 --iodepth=1 --output=op --allow_mounted_write=1 --filename=/dev/nvme2n1 --rw=write
fio: io_u error on file /dev/nvme2n1: Invalid argument: write offset=6295552, buflen=2048
[root@system ~]#
[root@system ~]#  /bin/fio --name=iops-wdpc --direct=1 --ioengine=libaio --bs=4096 --size=1024Gi --numjobs=1 --thread=1 --iodepth=1 --output=op --allow_mounted_write=1 --filename=/dev/nvme2n1 --rw=write
^C[root@system ~]# ^C3%][r=0KiB/s,w=147MiB/s][r=0,w=37.7k IOPS][eta 01h:57m:58s]
```

(fio version)

```
[root@smartiops ~]# /bin/fio --version
fio-3.1
```

Comment: 0.5Ki = 512 bytes, which is typical sector size (whatever it means for SSDs)

Comment: Yes, but fio fails with bs=512 bytes. I wanted to know how to test for bs=512 bytes?

Comment: I doubt the error you are seeing is caused by the `--bs=512` option. The block size on disks is typically 512 bytes. The disk is addressed using block numbers, thus the smallest block that can be read or written is 512 bytes. File systems typically use bigger block sizes, but if some software wants to interpret a file system by reading 512 bytes at a time, there is no reason it can't do so. The program just has to do multiple consecutive accesses to the disk to fill a buffer the size of a disk block in RAM.

Comment: fio did not work with bs=512, 1024, 2048 and works with bs=4096. (I have added screenshot of the same in question). What is wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As I was writing this I have become concerned about your setup. See the text in bold towards the end)

Using [`direct=1`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_man.html#cmdoption-arg-direct) will turn on the `O_DIRECT` flag on Linux which comes with alignment and size constraints when not ignored by lower levels of the stack (see the [information about `O_DIRECT` in the `open(2)` man page for more details](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)). If you're doing `O_DIRECT` I/O to a block device you MUST use a block size that is multiple of the disk's logical block size. For NVMe that's typically 4096 bytes but other values are possible depending on device configuration.

> In many cases, it requires device to be tested for bs=0.5Ki !! What is the rational[e] behind this?

When SSDs were first introduced they often emulated (see [512e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format#512e)) the logical block size of hard disks of the time to avoid breaking legacy software that assumed 512 byte logical block size/sectors but this could lead to suboptimal performance when I/O was poorly aligned (see these [slides about support the 4K sectors in Solaris](https://www.snia.org/sites/default/orig/sdc_archives/2009_presentations/wednesday/BoZhou_From512-4K.pdf)). Time has moved on and many devices are defaulting to not emulating such a small block size. You may want to talk to SNIA/the guide's authors about minimum block sizes in modern times (512 byte performance is becoming less interesting over time).

> What is wrong I am doing here?

You're not doing anything wrong - it's just you can't break the rules for using `O_DIRECT` with your given block device (I/O must be well aligned and must be a multiple of the disks logical block size).

> fio: how to test for bs less than 1 filesystem-block size?

It is strange that you to keep mentioning "filesystem" as your fio job description says you are going to a block device (`filename=/dev/nvme2n1`) and there won't be any Linux filesystems involved (which is a very reasonable thing for a particular type of testing). Your `tune2fs` command may be returning confusing results (as it is returning filesystem information!) and I think you meant to use `/sbin/blockdev --getss <device>` as `tune2fs` is only for things that have an ext* filesystem on top...

...I'm now worried about your setup. **If you are doing I/O to a block device on a system that has data that you can't afford to *permanently and irrecoverably be destroyed* please stop** and take some time to understand why you should not do fio block device access to block devices with "active" filesystems on them. Sorry for the warning but some of what you're saying suggests serious confusion and if there's data at risk... Oh gosh, I've just seen you are doing [`--allow_mounted_write=1`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-allow-mounted-write). All I can say is what you are doing looks **dangerous** and may lead to odd results and/or system crashes. As you've jumped the safety barrier I urge you do some background reading to achieve a better understanding before you continue.

If we assume your command's intent is correct and you mean "How can I directly benchmark a **device** with a block size less than the device's logical block size" the answer is: **you can't**. The device's logical block size is the smallest addressable unit the device exposes to the operating system and yours appears to 4096 bytes. You might be able to reconfigure the device to advertise 512 byte blocks but you will have to check with your device vendor as to how you do that (and it may imply a performance cost).

Comment: Many thanks Anon. You explained it very well. I did not know where I was missing but now I know the gaps in my knowledge and understanding. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3488903 you're very welcome! Apologies for the scary warning part way through but you would not believe the number of fio horror stories there are and using root with block devices is a good way for people to unintentionally lose data... At any rate, feel free to accept the answer on this and any other questions you've asked if you found it helpful (it provides encouragement to people to spend time writing longer answers).